# how to pass an optional value (NULL) in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I create an addressBook with this method :

```
func ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(_ options: CFDictionary!,
                          _ error:     UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFError>?>) -> Unmanaged<ABAddressBook>!
```

In the doc, options is reserved, pass NULL.

I have try to pass option like this :

```
var option:CFDictionaryRef?
```

It make an error : 
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

So what I can pass ?

Thank you

Comment: This may help you: https://github.com/SocialbitGmbH/SwiftAddressBook

Comment: Passing `nil` like `ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, ...)` works fine for me.

Comment: nil works, my problem was somewhere else, I forgot to check the authorization status before create the addressbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(nil, nil)

Should work.

The docs say you MUST pass nil (NULL) for the options parameter. Passing anything else is wrong, and may cause a crash.

Comment: nil works, my problem was somewhere else, I forgot to check the authorization status before create the addressbook.
Thanks you